# can I create a drop down list on the folium map in python?

Tags: python-3.x, drop-down-menu, leaflet, folium

can I render a drop down list on the folium map in python to switch between multiple data?

I know there is the option of layers, but i wanna use the dropdown list? is there any possible way to do that???

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `LayerControl` to a map. That will give you a list with layers with buttons. If you make a layer for each data source, you can switch between them.

```
m = folium.Map()
# add data layers
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

For a simple example check out this notebook:

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/FeatureGroup.ipynb

Comment: I already said I know there is an option of the layer control, but i need the dropdown list only

Comment: You said you knew the option of layers, not layer control. Can you be more specific? Do you have an example of what you want somewhere else? Why is layer control not  suitable for you?

Comment: I added `folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)`It took away my marker, and some other stuff, like when I have mouse over the map, it doesn't work. And there is no button, where I can change tiles.

Comment: **Solved** I had to add the `folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)`under everything. Before I had it at the top, but now I added it under my markers, and mouse over thing. Now it works.